# Adunit Id formats

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I've pubished Apps in the past, before Adsense was introduced.
The Adunit was in the format `a1234567890123c`, so in my layout I would have a line like

```
ads:adUnitId="a1234567890123c"
```

Now, the format is like `ca-app-pub-1234567890123456/1234567890`

So should my layout have this in the line

```
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1234567890123456/1234567890"
```

**Is the line in the activity still required, and will it be the new format?**

```
adView = new AdView( this, AdSize.BANNER, "ca-app-pub-1234567890123456/1234567890" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So should my layout have this in the line
>
> ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1234567890123456/1234567890"

Yes, if you are defining your Adview via XML.

> Is the line in the activity still required, and will it be the new
>   format?
>
> adView = new AdView( this, AdSize.BANNER,
>   "ca-app-pub-1234567890123456/1234567890"

Construction of the AdView in your Activity is only required if you haven't defined it via XML. Ie you either construct the AdView in XML or in code.

And yes, the AdUnitId in code is the same as that used in XML.